# Submission changed to a different status, but with the same explanation as the previous status

Tags: peer-review, journals, journal-workflow

(this line is added later ) : The length of the paper is only 3 pages.

Soon After Submission

> Article Status:  Reviewing
>
> Your paper is being reviewed by the journal’s editors and you will be contacted as soon as we have news.

After a month changed to

> Article Status:  Under Review
>
> Your paper is being reviewed by the journal’s editors and you will be contacted as soon as we have news.

Comment: See: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like. These two likely mean editorial assessment and peer review respectively, i.e. in the first case it's the editor checking it, and in the second reviewers have been invited.

Comment: Just one note, the status of my paper has been changed from  Reviewing to Under Review after three month and now is the Under Review too.  I suggest you to wait and concentrate on your next research.

Comment: @user0410 : thanks. May I know the journal name? Did the status explanation say editors or peer reviewers?

Comment: For your first question, my answer is No. For the second question: My status of paper is the same as your paper. Therefore,  please be patient.

Comment: Thats a valuble info. Thanks @user0410 . Looks like this status is the normal thing for this journal.

Answer (score 4):

**Initial answer**: *(This answer assumes a regular type of full-length paper submission in the standard journal workflow.)* This is probably an error in their explanation of the current status. The explanation is not in line with the [typical journal workflow](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like), especially the highlighted part:

> Article Status: Under Review
>
> Your paper is being reviewed by **the journal’s editors** and you will be contacted as soon as we have news.

In the typical journal workflow, the review is performed by the **invited reviewers**, rather than by the journal's editors.

You may contact the journal to task for clarification, but it probably won't matter in the end, as the process doesn't depend on this (incorrect) explanation.

**Updated answer**: *(This update takes into account that the submission only has three pages, and that the journal uses a decision-making step based on consensus between the editorial board members.)*  In this case, it's plausible that they're wont be additional reviewers involved. I speculate that the first status refers to the assigned editor handling the paper, and the second status refers to the editorial board making the decision. In this case, the status would not have any implication for the decision, other than removing the possibility of a desk-reject.

Comment: In that link (workflow), it is mentioned that, editorial assesment phase also can use the status "under review".

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju One particular system does that (and it arguably uses a slightly confusing terminology). However, unlike the system here, it doesn't have two separate status "Reviewing" and "Under review" with the same explanation.

Comment: This journal has a voting system by all members of the editorial board to make a decision. Can it be related to this?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Could be, even though this kind of decision process seems rather nonstandard in the first place. To be honest, in combination, these nonstandard procedures and erroneous/misleading descriptions don't cast the best possible light on the journal.

Comment: Its fairly reputed. Moreover the paper submitted is only of 3 pages. Would that cast any more light.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju That is fairly relevant context. In this case (which is rather exceptional), it's plausible that they're wont be additional reviewers involved.

Comment: In that case, which makes sense, whats the need of a status change?

Comment: Do you also mean/think its going to be a rejection for sure?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju I speculate that the first status refers to the assigned editor handling the paper, and the second status refers to the editorial board making the decision. In this case, the status would not have any implication for the decision, other than removing the possibility of a desk-reject.

Comment: a small mistake, its not voting but consensus.

Comment: Could you edit your answer in the new context?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Done

Answer (score -3):

It means that your paper is being reviewed by the journal's editors, and you will be contacted as soon as they have news.

...

What kind of answer were you expecting?

Comment: I know that. What Iam asking is what is  the indication of that change in the status when they both convey same meaning?